# How to Get IPA file from Xamarin Studio using MacinCloud

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create a .IPA file for iOS using Visual Studio from Windows Plateform. I have buy MacinCloud for iOS as a Xamarin Agent. Can anyone tell me the steps how can i generate an .IPA file. This .IPA file want to generate for my personal use not for distribution.

Thanks for your co-operation and help.

Answer (score 1):

All the instructions on how to generate an IPA are on the Xamarin Website here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/ipa_support/

Comment: thanks for your is that i need to get apple certificate for internal use or for only one device

Answer (score 0):

I think if you only want to have an internal use. We can try to achieve this even though with an unpaid Apple Account.

Firstly add your Apple ID in Xcode at Xcode => Preferences => Accounts.

Secondly, create a new project and make sure the `Bundle Identifier` is equal to your project which you want to deploy in Visutal Studio.

Then click the project in Xcode, you will see `Signing` column. Check the Automatically manage signing like:
[image]
After choosing a team, Xcode will create a signing certificate automatically, then running this project to your real device. After that you can deploy your original project on Visual Studio on real device too.

At last you can create your own ipa on Visual Studio by checking: Right click your project => properties => iOS IPA Options => Build iTunes Package Achieve(IPA) like:

[image]

Build this project, you will get an ipa at bin folder of this project. This ipa contains an automatically certification and the device which you build on Xcode. Moreover this ipa can only be used on this particular device.